# AngularJS - can´t execute methods with ng-click when markup is generated with a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I've created my paginator directive:

```
myApp.directive("paginator", function($timeout) {
  return {
  restrict: "E",
  link: function (scope, element, attr) {

    var totalProducts = scope.productsConfig.total,
        MAX_PER_PAGE = +(scope.productsConfig.limit),
        pagesQty = Math.ceil(totalProducts/MAX_PER_PAGE),
        markup = "";

    //Add initial markup ul open tag
    markup += "<ul class='ch-pagination'>";

    //Add the previous button if needed
    if(scope.lastStatus.p > 1) {
        //Then add the previous button
        var previousPage = +(scope.lastStatus.p) - 1;

        markup += "<li><a ng-click='goToPage(" + previousPage + ")'>Previous</a></li>";
    }

    //Add the elements
    for (var i = 1; i <= pagesQty; i++) {

        if(scope.lastStatus.p == i){
            var activeClass = "class='ch-pagination-current'";
        } else {
            activeClass = "";
        }

        markup += "<li " + activeClass + "><a ng-click='goToPage(" + i + ")'>" + i + "</a></li>"
    }

    //Add the next element if any
    if(scope.lastStatus.p < pagesQty) {
        //Then add the previous button
        var nextPage = +(scope.lastStatus.p) + 1;

        markup += "<li><a ng-click='goToPage(" + nextPage + ")'>Next</a></li>";
    }

    //Close the paginator
    markup += "</ul>";

    //Inject the code into the wrapper
    $(".inventory-paginator").html(markup);

}
```

}
});

Line where my method is injected (among others):

```
markup += "<li " + activeClass + "><a ng-click='goToPage(" + i + ")'>" + i + "</a></li>"
```

Then my method goToPage is called when clicking the generated markup. When using the paginator, trying to click some page button, nothing happens, ng-click never executes goToPage method, even when the generated markup is:

```
 "ng-click='goToPage(2)'"
```

The method inside the main controller:

```
$scope.goToPage = function (intPage) {
    var requestUrl = $scope.buildSearchRequestUrl(intPage);
    console.log("goToPage requestUrl: " + requestUrl);

    //Request the data, on success show the table again
    $http.get(requestUrl)
    .success(function (data) {
        $scope.inventoryData = data;
    }).error(function (data) {
        if(window.console){
            console.log("The article couldnt be paused");
        }
    });
}
```

I´m guessing that Im missing some linking, but can´t figure out where, or why.

Thanks so much in advance,

Guillermo

Comment: Generating markup like that is a really bad idea, you're basically using an MVC framework to generate spaghetti. Separate your markup in a template which you include in the `template` property of the directive or in a separate file that you specify in `templateUrl`, and all will be fixed. You could compile that whole thing but why would you complicate your life like that...?

Comment: Joe, I understand that it's a bad idea, but I'm forced to use a ui framework based in jQuery and need to make it work. Compiling the directive did the trick, it's working now.
Really understand your point, but sometimes it's good to know how to do not so good things using not so good practices to achieve the result. Thanks a lot for your time and your answer, have a nice weekend.

Comment: declaring the markup in `template` or `templateUrl` and jquery in the link function is a completely normal way of handling this type of scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to compile it? A directive should be compiled whenever you want to invoke it from HTML.

See http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: You rock!, that did the trick: Injected $compile into the directive, then followed the guidelines.

As procedure I will compile every directive outputting code.

Thanks buddy! Have a nice weekend.

Answer (score 2):

As roland pointed out you must use the `$compile` service to compile the html and then append it directive element. Without the $compile step angular has no way to link the ng-click directives.

```
myApp.directive("paginator", function($timeout, $compile) {
  return {
  restrict: "E",
  link: function (scope, element, attr) {

    var totalProducts = scope.productsConfig.total,
        MAX_PER_PAGE = +(scope.productsConfig.limit),
        pagesQty = Math.ceil(totalProducts/MAX_PER_PAGE),
        markup = "";

    //Add initial markup ul open tag
    markup += "<ul class='ch-pagination'>";

    //Add the previous button if needed
    if(scope.lastStatus.p > 1) {
        //Then add the previous button
        var previousPage = +(scope.lastStatus.p) - 1;

        markup += "<li><a ng-click='goToPage(" + previousPage + ")'>Previous</a></li>";
    }

    //Add the elements
    for (var i = 1; i <= pagesQty; i++) {

        if(scope.lastStatus.p == i){
            var activeClass = "class='ch-pagination-current'";
        } else {
            activeClass = "";
        }

        markup += "<li " + activeClass + "><a ng-click='goToPage(" + i + ")'>" + i + "</a>   </li>"
        }

    //Add the next element if any
    if(scope.lastStatus.p < pagesQty) {
        //Then add the previous button
        var nextPage = +(scope.lastStatus.p) + 1;

        markup += "<li><a ng-click='goToPage(" + nextPage + ")'>Next</a></li>";
    }

    //Close the paginator
    markup += "</ul>";

    //append and compile code to element
    element.append($compile(markup)(scope));

});
```